# Why operator $f(x)\mapsto x^2f(x)$ has no cyclic vector

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $L_2(-1,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and operator $A:L_2(-1,1)\rightarrow L_2(-1,1)$ defined as $(Af)(x)=x^2f(x)$. I want to prove that there's no cyclic vector, that means $\forall f\in L_2(-1,1)$
$$\textrm{cl  span}\{x^{2n}f(x)\}\not=L_2(-1,1)$$
I started with considering a.e.even functions $f$. Statement holds for them because there exist non-even integrable functions, obviously. But I don't see a way to continue, I think may be there's a better idea?

P. S. I heard that "orthogonality" might help, but I don't understand how to apply it here.

Thanks!

Comment: It denotes closure of linear span of $f, x^2f, x^4f, ...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to show that given any $f\in L^2(-1,1)$ there exists $g\in L^2(-1,-1)$ that is orthogonal to $x^{2n}f(x)$ for all $n$. Let us define
$$
g(x)=x\,\overline{f(-x)}.
$$
We clearly have $g\in L^2(-1,1)$, and
$$
\langle A^nf,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1x^{2n+1}f(x)f(-x)\,dx=0, 
$$
since the integrand is odd. This shows that
$$
\big[\operatorname{span}\{A^nf:\ n\in\mathbb N\}\big]^\perp\ne\{0\}, 
$$
which prevents the subspace from being dense.

Comment: It's just brilliant

Comment: I wouldn't say it's brilliant, but it's neater that a couple dumb things I tried first :D